# Is there a way to get all possible protobuf Enum values using scalapb?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I have a protobuf enum like

```
enum MyEnum {
A = 0;
B = 1; 
C = 2;
}
```

At runtime, I want to loop over all possible values for the enum like this:

```
MyEnum().uniqueValues.forEach(println)
```

How might I do this with scalapb or just in scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use [scalapb](https://scalapb.github.io/docs/) with default settings, a following protobuf enumeration type

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 0;
  B = 1; 
  C = 2;
}
```

will be converted into an abstract class with a companion object

```scala
sealed abstract class MyEnum(val value: _root_.scala.Int) extends _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnum 
???
object MyEnum extends _root_.scalapb.GeneratedEnumCompanion[MyEnum]
```

And the companion object `MyEnum` will be providing method `values` you need

```scala
lazy val values = scala.collection.immutable.Seq(A, B, C)
```

So, you can access it via `MyEnum.values` or via `MyEnum.A.companion.values`